# Ansible - using {{ item }} with csvfile lookups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to work out a way to cut down on lines of code for various modules, repeating stanzas seems pointless. I'd like to use csvfile lookups to help fill in blanks. Take for example the following CSV:

```
# groups.csv
# name, gid [optional - leave blank], state [present|absent], system [yes|no]

accounts,502,present,no
engineering,504,present,no
```

So, I have all my group definitions in csv format. The problem is, processing it, no matter what I try I cannot get lookups to work inside the groups module.
So initially, I wanted to do this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost

  become: True
  become_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: get groups
    command: /usr/bin/awk -F',' '!/^#/ && !/^$/ { print $1 }' groups.csv
    register: groups_out

  - debug: var=groups_out.stdout_lines


  - name: Process groups
    group: >
      name="{{ lookup('csvfile', 'item file=groups.csv col=0') }}"
      gid="{{ lookup('csvfile', 'item file=groups.csv col=1') }}"
      state="{{ lookup('csvfile', 'item file=groups.csv col=2') }}"
      system="{{ lookup('csvfile', 'item file=groups.csv col=3') }}"
    # with_lines: "/usr/bin/awk -F',' '!/^#/ && !/^$/ { print $1 }' groups.csv"
    # with_items: "{{ groups_out.stdout_lines }}"
    with_lines: "{{ groups_out.stdout_lines }}"
```

The result of which is this:

```
    TASK [Process groups] **********************************************************
/bin/sh: accounts: command not found
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "lookup_plugin.lines(accounts) returned 127"}
```

As you can see from the code, I've also tried using with_items and with_lines using the awk command directly, however it appears the groups module doesn't like me doing this.

Ansible 2.1.1.0 on Centos 7.
Python 2.7.5
Jinja 2.8

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

R

Comment: What are the permissions of the "/var/tmp/ansible.csv" file, and does that jive with what user is running the "ansible" or "ansible-playbook" or what user the command is being run as?

Comment: That's the thing - there's no such file called /var/tmp/ansible.csv. /var/tmp is my cwd.

Comment: Changed `item + 'file-...` to `'item file=...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below. Thanks to Jon and Kai on the ansible-project googlegroup for their assistance.

```
---

- hosts: localhost

  become: True
  become_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: get groups
    command: /usr/bin/awk -F',' '!/^#/ && !/^$/ { print $1 }' /var/tmp/groups.csv
    register: groups_out

  - name: Process groups one
    group: >
      name={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=0 delimiter=,') }}
      gid={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=1 delimiter=,') }}
      state={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=2 delimiter=,') }}
      system={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=3 delimiter=,') }}
    with_items: "{{ groups_out.stdout_lines }}"
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Process groups two
    group: >
      name={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=0 delimiter=,') }}
      gid={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=1 delimiter=,') }}
      state={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=2 delimiter=,') }}
      system={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=groups.csv col=3 delimiter=,') }}
    with_lines: /usr/bin/awk -F',' '!/^#/ && !/^$/ { print $1 }' /var/tmp/groups.csv
```